# JSON Bulk import to Elasticstearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Bulk import.

I need to import the Products as individual items.

I have a json file that looks similar to the following:

```
{
   "Products":[
      {
         "Title":"Product 1",
         "Description":"Product 1 Description",
         "Size":"Small",
         "Location":[
            {
               "url":"website.com",
               "price":"9.99",
               "anchor":"Prodcut 1"
            }
         ],
         "Images":[
            {
               "url":"product1.jpg"
            }
         ],
         "Slug":"prodcut1"
      },
      {
         "Title":"Product 2",
         "Description":"Prodcut 2 Desctiption",
         "Size":"large",
         "Location":[
            {
               "url":"website2.com",
               "price":"99.94",
               "anchor":"Product 2"
            },
            {
               "url":"website3.com",
               "price":"79.95",
               "anchor":"discount product 2"
            }
         ],
         "Images":[
            {
               "url":"image.jpg"
            },
            {
               "url":"image2.jpg"
            }
         ],
         "Slug":"product2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried the following (I'm a novice at this):

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @products.json
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' -d @products.json
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/cp/products -d "@products.json"
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/products -d "@products.json"
```

Some gave an error others didn't.  What do I need to do?

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/postgres-streams-to-elastic-streams/92798 
any pointers on this one !

Answer (score 33):

Following the [Bulk API documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). You need to supply the bulk operation with a file formatted very specifically:

> NOTE: the final line of data must end with a newline character \n.
>
> The possible actions are index, create, delete and update. index and create expect a source on the next line, and have the same semantics as the op_type parameter to the standard index API (i.e. create will fail if a document with the same index and type exists already, whereas index will add or replace a document as necessary). delete does not expect a source on the following line, and has the same semantics as the standard delete API. update expects that the partial doc, upsert and script and its options are specified on the next line.
>
> If you’re providing text file input to curl, you must use the --data-binary flag instead of plain -d. The latter doesn’t preserve newlines.

So you will need to change the contents of your products.json file to the following:

```
 {"index":{"_index":"cp", "_type":"products", "_id": "1"}}
 { "Title":"Product 1", "Description":"Product 1 Description", "Size":"Small", "Location":[{"url":"website.com", "price":"9.99", "anchor":"Prodcut 1"}],"Images":[{ "url":"product1.jpg"}],"Slug":"prodcut1"}
 {"index":{"_index":"cp", "_type":"products", "_id":"2"}}
 {"Title":"Product 2", "Description":"Prodcut 2 Desctiption", "Size":"large","Location":[{"url":"website2.com", "price":"99.94","anchor":"Product 2"},{"url":"website3.com","price":"79.95","anchor":"discount product 2"}],"Images":[{"url":"image.jpg"},{"url":"image2.jpg"}],"Slug":"product2"}
```

And be sure to use `--data-binary` in your curl command (like your first command). Also note the `index` and `type` can be omitted if you use the index and type specific endpoint. Yours is `/cp/products` like your 3rd curl command.

Comment: `_id` is not required. If omitted Elasticsearch will auto-generate one.

Comment: Also worth noting: The endpoints are `/_bulk`, `/{index}/_bulk`, and `{index}/{type}/_bulk`. When the `index` or the `index/type` are provided, they will be used by default on bulk items that don’t provide them explicitly.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/postgres-streams-to-elastic-streams/92798 
any pointers on this one !

Answer (score 9):

This was fast and worked for me on an array of JSON objects.

```
cat data.json | \
jq -c '.[]  | .id = ._id | del (._id) | {"index": {"_index": "profiles", "_type": "gps", "_id": .id}}, .' |\
curl  -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
```

I had to do the copy and delete of the `_id` field as the import threw an error (*Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.*) if it was not renamed. Most data is unlikely to have an `_id` field in which case this part should be omitted.

Credit for this to [Kevin Marsh](http://kevinmarsh.com/2014/10/23/using-jq-to-import-json-into-elasticsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm! I have used original solution  `cat file.json | jq -c '.[] | {"index": {"_index": "bookmarks", "_type": "bookmark", "_id": .id}}, .' | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-`

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing a bash script that is "not at all optimized" to do this for me.  The dataset is relatively small so this will work for my needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
CURLURL="http://127.0.0.1:9200/cp/products"
COUNT=$(less products.json | jq '.Products | length')    
while [  $COUNTER -lt $COUNT ]; do
  echo $COUNTER
  CURLDATA=$(less products.json | jq '.Products['$COUNTER']')
  RESPONSE=$(curl -XPOST "$CURLURL"  -d "$CURLDATA" -vn)
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

Comment: If you're getting a "jq:  command not found" error you can install jq from here:  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ (most likely)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to add the necessary headers with the following `sed` script:

```
sed -e 's/^/{ "index" : {} }\n/' -i products.json
```

This will add an empty index above each line in the file.  An empty index is allowed as long as the index and type are specified in the URL.  After that, the proper call would be

```
curl -s -XPOST http://localhost:9200/cp/products/_bulk --data-binary @products.json
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [json-to-es-bulk](https://github.com/mradamlacey/json-to-es-bulk) tool.

Run the following to convert your JSON file to NDJSON:

```
node ./index.js -f file.json --index index_name --type type_name
```

It will create the `request-data.txt` file, which can be imported with bulk:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@request-data.txt"
```